# Haversine formula gives different result then what is showing on google map . How to tackle this issue?

Tags: android, location, haversine

I am using the haversine formula for drive-thru functionality in my app. But for some reason, it gives me around 30 - 40 meters less calculation then what was showing on google Maps.

I am using the GPS coordinates of a device that is corrected but don't know why it's happening over here.